# Regular expression to get the value inside double curly braces "{{ }}"

Tags: php, regex

Regular expression in PHP to fetch the text quoted inside with "{{ }}" in an array.

For eg:

```
$str = "This is sample content with a dynamic value {{value1}} and also have more dynamic values {{value2}}, {{value3}}";
```

Need output as like below array,

```
array(value1,value2,value3);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i am not very good in the regular expression and tried by referring this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work:

```
$str = "This is sample content with a dynamic value {{value1}} and also have more dynamic values {{value2}}, {{ value3 }}";
if (preg_match_all("~\{\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}~", $str, $arr))
   var_dump($arr[1]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "value2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "value3"
}
```

Comment: i need to have array exact match inside the curly braces because i have to check whether the array has index "1". Can u tell me without braces values will always comes on array index "1"?

Comment: Yes it will always be `$arr[1]` since it related to matching group #1 i.e. expression inside square brackets.

Comment: I have one little thing to do need to trim spaces inside curly braces. For eg: if i give like this {{ value1 }}. is it possible in the same expression itself?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
preg_match_all('~\{\{(.*?)\}\}~', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(6) "value1"
  [1] =>
  string(6) "value2"
  [2] =>
  string(6) "value3"
}
```

Comment: Its working. But i need to have array exact match inside the curly braces because i have to check whether the array has index "1". Can u tell me without braces values will always comes on array index "1"?

Comment: That's because the value between braces will be matched by group 1. That's because of the `()`. The `$matches` array will first contain the whole match and then the matching group 1, 2, ... That's how it works

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/', $str, $matches);
$array = $matches[1];
```