# How to include EOL in this regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex which can extract any substrings like `{{string}}`
my regex: `'/{{+(.*?)}}/'`

and I need to modify it where it could extract strings like
`{{ something -enter-char-\r-OR\r\n- somthing }}`

```
function replace_callback($matches)
{
    // just in case
    if ( !isset($matches[1]) || !is_string($matches[1]) ) throw new Exception(__FUNCTION__.': invalid $matches[1].');
    // detected var without brackets
    $var = $matches[1];

    // my program's processing on $var

    return $var;
}

$text = ' sdfhh fdfdf {{do:somecoolthings}} sdfggg';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/{{+(.*?)}}/',
    'replace_callback',
    $text
);
```

thanks in advance!

Edit: The people who see questions like this are programmers who don't have as much knowledge about regex, and this question asks a different goal than the other 2 "duplicate" questions, and I'm sure this post will become useful to someone.

final code:

```
function replace_callback($matches)
{
    // just in case
    if ( !isset($matches[1]) || !is_string($matches[1]) ) throw new Exception(__FUNCTION__.': invalid $matches[1].');
    // detected var without brackets
    $var = $matches[1];

    // my program's processing on $var

    return $var;
}

$text = ' sdfhh fdfdf {{
do:somecoolthings
}} sdfggg';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/{{(.*?)}}/s',
    'replace_callback',
    $text
);
```

Comment: Use `'/{{(.*?)}}/s'`

Comment: thanks a lot, if you write it as answer I will choose it as best answer, if u like.

Comment: The answer like this can easily be found on SO and in the Web, no need to post another one.

Comment: should I delete this then? People could use this piece of code tho!

Comment: You do not have to delete the question, but you may. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316891/regular-expression-to-get-the-value-inside-double-curly-braces is easy to find, and the other one about the `s` modifier is also easy to find.

Comment: that one didn't have support for special chars like `\n`

Comment: It is not a rocket science to search for `regex spanning multiple lines` in Google. You'd get the answer quicker than writing all these comments.

Comment: hey do know the javascript version of `'/{{(.*?)}}/s'` ?

Comment: `var rx = /{{([\s\S]*?)}}/g`

Comment: Thanks dude, I just found this awesome website about regex http://regexr.com/  perfect for learning

Comment: Yeah, it is popular. However, it only supports JS regex. If you want to test PCRE/Python regexes, too, use http://regex101.com

Comment: Awesome thanks! you're a regex god aren't ya...